# R: sort a data frame by a numeric column of repeated numbers

Tags: r

I have a data frame that looks like this:

> ```
>  Gene         Cluster       
>   A              0        
>   B              0        
>   C              7        
>   D              7        
>   F              1        
>   G              1
>   H              2
>   I              3
>   L              8
>   M              8
>   Z              8
> ```

I would like to sort the data.frame by the numeric column "cluster" in the following order:

> order = c(1,0,8,7,3,2)

With a column of factors I usually use "match" but with a numeric column of repeated numbers I don't know exactly how to sort the rows with my desired order.

Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your thought to use `match` is correct, now just include `order(.)` as well:

```r
dat[order(match(dat$Cluster, c(1,0,8,7,3,2))),]
#    Gene Cluster
# 5     F       1
# 6     G       1
# 1     A       0
# 2     B       0
# 9     L       8
# 10    M       8
# 11    Z       8
# 3     C       7
# 4     D       7
# 8     I       3
# 7     H       2
```

FYI, according to [`?order`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/order.html),

```
                The sort used is _stable_ (except for 'method =
     "quick"'), so any unresolved ties will be left in their original
     ordering.
```

So the code above by-itself should not change the ordering of `Gene` within its `Cluster`s. If your data has more columns, you can always add tie-breakers in follow-on arguments; for instance, if you wanted to *ensure* that it is also sorted lexicographically by `Gene` within each `Cluster`, then you would use

```r
order(match(dat$Cluster, c(1,0,8,7,3,2)), dat$Gene)
# or perhaps more readable
with(dat, match(Cluster, c(1,0,8,7,3,2)), Gene))
```

Comment: Okkk that was the piece I lost. Thank you so much!